# steps to create a back-up file(.bak) from a database server file(.mdf) in visual studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, web-deployment

I need to know the step by step process on how to create a back-up file with .bak extension from my database server file (.mdf) in my visual studio 2012 ultimate.

I need to get a back up file (.bak) from my database server file because it needs on the deployment of my website to a web host server to restore my database.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: I was just knew about making back-up files now I realize about using windows powershell but also a little bit confused about the commands. Can u give me a sample format of the command in powershell on creating back-ups?

Comment: From SQL Server Management Studio, connect to a database engine instance. Then right-click in Object Explorer and choose "Start Powershell". You can then use `Get-Help Backup-SqlDatabase` to learn the full command syntax. Of course, you can also use Management Studio, right-click a database and choose "Tasks->Back up".

Comment: Just use SSMS to backup. You can also set maintenance plan as well.